# Why Hatcher didn't mention about $A_{\beta}$?

Tags: algebraic-topology

Reference :Algebraics Topology  by Allen Hatcher

Lemma $1.15$.: If a space $X$ is the union of a collection of path-connected open sets $A_{\alpha}$ each containing the base point $x_0\in X$ and if each intersection $A_{\alpha}\cap A_{\beta}$ is path-connected, then **every loop in $X$ at $x_0$ is homotopic to a product of loops each of which is contained in a single** $A_{\alpha}$.

Diagram [image]

From the diagram we can conclude that  every loop in $X$ at $x_0$ is homotopic to a product of loops each of which is contained in a single $A_{\alpha}$  and $A_{\beta}$

**My confusion**: In the last sentence, Why Hachter  didn't mention  about $A_{\beta}$  ?

**My thinking** :  All loops  are  contained  in  both $A_{\alpha}$  and $A_{\beta}$

Comment: What exactly is your confusion? $\alpha$ here is just a dummy variable, meaning it represents any element of the indexing set. So when he says "an $A_\alpha$" he means any member of the collection covering $X.$

Comment: ok @D.Brogan that means   every loop in $X$ at $x_0$ is homotopic to a product of loops each of which is contained in  either  $A_{\alpha}$  or $A_{\beta}$. Am i right ?

Comment: @jasmine "... every loop in $X$ at $x_0$ is homotopic to a product of loops each of which is contained *in a single element of the collection $\{A_\alpha\}_{\alpha}$*."

Comment: There could me many $A_\alpha$'s. There could be two, in which case you could call them $A_\alpha$ and $A_\beta$ or there could be a thousand in which case you'd need a different naming scheme. There could be infinitely many (countable or uncountable). The picture here is just using two sets, $A_\alpha$ and $A_\beta$ as an example because it's quite hard to draw "arbitrarily many" open sets.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a somewhat more formal statement.

Suppose we have some set $I$ and a function $A : I \to P(X)$ such that $A(\alpha)$ is a path-connected open neighbourhood of $x_0$ for all $\alpha \in I$. Suppose further that for all $\alpha, \beta \in I$, $A(\alpha) \cap A(\beta)$ is path-connected. Then every loop with base point $x_0$ is homotopic to the product of loops $\ell_1, ..., \ell_n$, such that for each $i$ s.t. $1 \leq i \leq n$, there is some $\alpha_i \in I$ such that the range of $\ell_i$ lies entirely within $A(\alpha_i)$.